Can I reuse output_field instance in Django ORM or I should always create a duplicate?
I have a Django codebase that does a lot of Case/When/ExpressionWrapper/Coalesce/Cast ORM functions and some of them sometimes need a field as an argument - output_field.
from django.db.models import FloatField, F
some_param1=Sum(F('one_value')*F('second_value'), output_field=FloatField())
some_param2=Sum(F('one_value')*F('second_value'), output_field=FloatField())
some_param3=Sum(F('one_value')*F('second_value'), output_field=FloatField())
some_param4=Sum(F('one_value')*F('second_value'), output_field=FloatField())
some_param5=Sum(F('one_value')*F('second_value'), output_field=FloatField())

Sometimes I find myself wondering why am I always creating the same instance of any Field subclass over and over again. Is there any difference if I just pass one instance and share it between expressions? F.E
from django.db.models import FloatField, F

float_field = FloatField()

some_param1=Sum(F('one_value')*F('second_value'), output_field=float_field)
some_param2=Sum(F('one_value')*F('second_value'), output_field=float_field)
some_param3=Sum(F('one_value')*F('second_value'), output_field=float_field)
some_param4=Sum(F('one_value')*F('second_value'), output_field=float_field)
some_param5=Sum(F('one_value')*F('second_value'), output_field=float_field)

I coulnd't find it in a documentation and the source code is not documented well regarding this parameter.
P.S. The example is fake, just imagine a big annotate function that does a lot of processing using Case/When/ExpressionWrapper/Coalesce/Cast and has a lot of duplicated Field instances as output_field.

you can use the same one, since it is more used for its SQL type, and for lookups. But I don't really see any added value converting the first one in the second: constructing a FloatField runs in microseconds.

I understand that, but when it's used around 30-40 times in ONE annotate i think if it can speed up the code execution even for a little bit it would be nice.
the code needs to be refactored I know but for now I am trying to speed it up at least a little.

I doubt that, because typically the largest overhead is sending the query to the database, and retrieving the data. Typically this takes magnitudes more time.

with %timeit FloatField() it says "3.82 µs ± 379 ns per loop", so that would be at most 160 microseconds. Likely it is more code caching: if you run a program a second time, the bytecode is still in the cache, so the calls itself work faster, you always need to test program 1 and then  program 2, and then the reverse.

You can reuse the field. Using this output_field=… [Django-doc] serves two purposes:

the type sometimes requires specific formatting, typically for GIS columns, since a point, polygon, etc. needs to be converted to text so that Django can understand it; and
to know what lookups transformations, etc. can be applied on it.

Indeed, if we use:
queryset = queryset.annotate(
    some_param1=Sum(
        F('one_value') * F('second_value'), output_field=CharField()
    )
)
then Django will assume that some_param1 is a CharField (here this does not make much sense), and thus you can use:
queryset.filter(some_param1__lower='a')
since __lower is defined as a lookup on a CharField. But for a FloatField, it does not make much sense.
But the field is not specialized or altered. It is thus more of a "signal" object to specify what can be done with it.
That being said, I don't see much reasons to convert code to prevent constructing a FloatField. If we use %timeit, we get:
In [1]: %timeit FloatField()
3.82 µs ± 379 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

So the construction takes approximately 3.82 microseconds. Typically a view has a lot more work to do than that, so writing a query that is itself more efficient, or saving a roundtrip to the database, will (very) likely outperform any optimization with respect to saving a FloatField by a few magnitudes.
